# Automatically determine dependencies from a collection of table Object script files

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a folder /Tables that contain all the table objects scripts. Some of these table objects have dependency between each other hence the need for the script to be executed in order. For now we have to edit our bat file if dependency collision occur and fix it in the order needed. Since every morning we have a push using OSQL cmd line switch to push these table to a staging database server. Is there a way to automate the order of the table objects scripts by dynamically?

Comment: Do you have an existing database that you could script the dependency order from?  It's difficult to automatically determine dependencies just from a collection of script files.  A table-driven list of dependencies could easily be read to give you the order to run the scripts.  This list can be automatically generated from the database.

Comment: Do you want to control the order in which you execute a collection of script files OR is your question on script generation from SSMS or SMO?

Comment: @Chad the question is to control the order. I am using powershell script at the moment and hoping that with powershell script I can just point it to the /Tables folders, then call my recursive function to go through the object script and knows it automatically which object script to execute based on their dependencies.

Comment: @mellamokb Yes I am trying to automatically determine dependencies just from a collection of script files.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to determine dependencies from the script files.  You'd have to parse everything and keep track of the dependencies.  Another approach, if you have a single object per file (i.e. one table, view, etc.), is to keep track of which files have not been executed successfully, and loop through the list until it's empty.  Depending on how deeply nested your dependencies are, you might have to make lots of passes, but chances are good that the list will get short very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Compare Pro will probably be able to do this if you specify your folder of tables as a scripts folder source database. Point it to your target (which could be an empty database) and run through the Synchronization Wizard to generate a script in dependency order.

Comment: +1 yes I have looked into it. I'm wondering if you can use Redgate SDK to integrate with the automation.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be very difficult to determine dependencies from the script files. You'd have to parse everything and keep track of the dependencies. Another approach, if you have a single object per file (i.e. one table, view, etc.), is to keep track of which files have not been executed successfully, and loop through the list until it's empty. Depending on how deeply nested your dependencies are, you might have to make lots of passes, but chances are good that the list will get short very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Found another approach which is to use Visual Studio 2010 database project. You can import any user defined scripts or folders having multiple scripts into Visual Studio 2010 database projects. Dependencies are compiled by the visual studio and deployment can be made to multiple databases.